# BeautifulSoup парсит не всю таблицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

У меня возникла следующая проблема: имеется кусок html-кода со страницы
https://steelwillknives.com/our-knives/urban-series/sedge-f19m-10.html :

```
<div class="features">
  <big>Specifications</big>
    <table>
      <tr><td>Steel:</td><td>D2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Handle:</td><td>G10</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Sheath material:</td><td>-</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Finish:</td><td>Satin</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lock Type:</td><td>Liner Lock</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Folded length:</td><td>4.33"</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Full length:</td><td>7.76"</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Blade length:</td><td>3.4"</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Blade thickness:</td><td>0.12"</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Weight:</td><td>2.96</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Pivot Type:</td><td>Bronze washers</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Это часть html-кода страницы описывает данную таблицу, текст которой я хочу спрасить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо спарсить весь текст таблицы и я пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом:

```
import requests as req 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = req.get('https://steelwillknives.com/our-knives/urban-series/sedge-f19m-10.html').text
soup = BS(r,'lxml')
features = soup.find('main').find('div', class_='white-block').find('div', class_='features')
trs = features.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    lines = tr.find('td').text
    print(lines)
```

Однако, в данном случае выводит мне только первый столбец таблицы:

```
Steel:
Handle:
Sheath material:
Finish:
Lock Type:
Folded length:
Full length:
Blade length:
Blade thickness:
Weight:
Pivot Type:
```

Почему так происходит я понимаю, однако как реализовать решение так, чтобы выводило и второй столбец я не знаю.
Соответственно, мой вопрос заключается в следующем: **как сделать так, чтобы выводился текст и второго столбца?**

Comment: с предыдущим вопросом и [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1272098/420098) на него все получилось?

Comment: Да, отлично, спасибо – все работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что `tr.find('td')` ищет только первый элемент 'td', а их по два в каждой строке...
Попробуйте с `tr.find_all('td')`. Работает:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''
<div class="features">
    <big>Specifications</big>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Steel:</td><td>D2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Handle:</td><td>G10</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Sheath material:</td><td>-</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Finish:</td><td>Satin</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Lock Type:</td><td>Liner Lock</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Folded length:</td><td>4.33"</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Full length:</td><td>7.76"</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Blade length:</td><td>3.4"</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Blade thickness:</td><td>0.12"</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Weight:</td><td>2.96</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Pivot Type:</td><td>Bronze washers</td></tr>
        </table>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

trs = soup.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print(f'{tds[0].text} {tds[1].text}')
```

Выводит:

```
Steel: D2
Handle: G10
Sheath material: -
Finish: Satin
Lock Type: Liner Lock
Folded length: 4.33"
Full length: 7.76"
Blade length: 3.4"
Blade thickness: 0.12"
Weight: 2.96
Pivot Type: Bronze washers
```